# How to retrieve values of non selected row in HTML datatable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I trying to get the value of all rows that not clicked on their buttons. For example when I click to the button on first row, I want to retrieve the values of the rows without the clicked one.

```js
 
var table = document.getElementById("all_department");
if (table != null) {
  for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  table.rows[i].onclick = function() {
  tableText(this);
      }
    }
  }    
    
function tableText(tableRow) {
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(tableRow);
console.log(myJSON);
}
```

```html
    <table id="all_departments">
     <thead>
              <th><button>click</button></th>                                   
              <th>Departments</th>
              <th>Creation Date</th>
              <th>Name</th>
     </thead>
    <tbody class="bl">
           <tr>
                <td><button>click</button></td>
                <td>Management</td>
                <td>2-3-2016</td>
                <td>client x</td>
          </tr>
    
           <tr>
                <td><button>click</button></td>
                <td>Sales</td>
                <td>25-6-2019</td>
                <td>client y</td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: what does that mean ? Value of rows ? Which value ?

Comment: @SrushtiShah yes for example  when I click on row I want to get the values of the others rows that's not clicked sale,25-6-2019,client y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to click handler on buttons, get the parent tr of clicked button and then get the siblings.

Once you get all the siblings we can loop over them and form our result string.

Please refer the code below

```js
const allBtns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
allBtns.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let elem = this.closest('tr');
    const siblings = getSiblings(elem);
    const result = [];
    siblings.map(ele => {
      ele.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((e, i) => {
        if (i !== 0) {
          result.push(e.innerText);
        }
      });
    });
    console.log(result.join(','));
  })
});

const getSiblings = function(e) {
  let siblings = [];
  if (!e.parentNode) {
    return siblings;
  }

  let sibling = e.parentNode.firstChild;

  while (sibling) {
    if (sibling.nodeType === 1 && sibling !== e) {
      siblings.push(sibling);
    }
    sibling = sibling.nextSibling;
  }
  return siblings;
};
```

```html
<table id="all_departments">
  <thead>
    <th><button>click</button></th>
    <th>Departments</th>
    <th>Creation Date</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="bl">
    <tr>
      <td><button>click</button></td>
      <td>Management</td>
      <td>2-3-2016</td>
      <td>client x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>click</button></td>
      <td>Sales</td>
      <td>25-6-2019</td>
      <td>client y</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```